# 3DS Security check in MasterCard Gateway

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, mastercard

Im trying to implement payments using MasterCard Gateway for android i follow the steps in the documentation i reach the step where i get the HTML Response for 3DS i use testing card to check it but the issue when i click submit in the 3ds check i got authorization error i will attach images below, Anyone know why i got this error, I know the error says that's an authorization issue but i got the html reponse using the api passowrd and merchantId, What other thing im missing here?

If anyone used this sdk before i will be happy to know what's the steps he follows because the documentation says nothing and just gives some headlines to implement the sdk.

Thanks all.

[image]

[image: error i got]